# SQL query fetches no value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run a SQL query which fetches no value.

```
select distinct gd.segment1 
from INV_GENERIC_DISPOSITIONS gd, gl_code_combinations gcc
where gd.distribution_account = gcc.code_combination_id
  and sysdate between gd.disable_date and gd.enable_date;
```

This is the query and `disable_date` has null values and hence the complete query does not return any value.

Comment: Evolve! No one should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you want logic like this:

```
select distinct gd.segment1
from INV_GENERIC_DISPOSITIONS gd join
     gl_code_combinations gcc
     on gd.distribution_account = gcc.code_combination_id and
        (sysdate <= enable_date and
         sysdate >= gd.disable_date or gd.disable_date is null
        );
```

Note that this use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ISNULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to specify a backup value when the one rferenced is null.

```
select distinct gd.segment1 from INV_GENERIC_DISPOSITIONS gd JOIN gl_code_combinations gcc 
 on gd.distribution_account = gcc.code_combination_id
where gd.distribution_account = gcc.code_combination_id
and sysdate between ISNULL(gd.disable_date, replacement_value) and gd.enable_date;
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: edited for clarity  and because i agree with you, but in this setting where i don't know much about table definitions (as OP did not provide any) i kept the OG query and just added what i tough could be useful for them